# Output of this selenium with cucumber code is confusing

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

When i run this code in eclipse,
under console tab it is showing :
**0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0.000s**

under junit tab it is showing :
[image]

and also the test should fail right??

TestRunner.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "resources")
public class Runner {

}
```

stepDefinition.java

```
public class stepDefinition{

}
```

Test0.feature

```
Feature: This will test the following features :
        1) Login
        2) Logout  

Scenario: User successfully Logs in 
Given: When user is on login page 
When: user clicks on "Sign in" button 
And: user enters username and password
Then: Home page is displayed.

Scenario: User successfully Logs out 
Given: When user is on home page 
When: user clicks on his "avatar" icon 
And: user clicks on "log out" option from the drop down.
Then: Login page is displayed.
```

so, why the test has passed? and why is it showing as 0 scenarios in console?
please help!!

Comment: What you have in your stepdefinition class?

Comment: Nothing.. just an empty class

Comment: Can you post the code in your step definition class? If the steps are defined, but contain no code or do not throw an exception, then the tests will pass. Failed tests mean the tests or steps throw an exception.

Comment: Even after deleting stepdefiniton.java getting same results..:-(

Comment: How is your project structured? It looks like Cucumber is not finding your feature files. Make sure they are in the default location or specify where to find them in your Runner.